# A convenient way to typeset this diagram of the three MIPS instruction formats

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, diagrams

What is a convenient way to typeset the following table/diagram of the bit fields of the three types of MIPS CPU instructions?

[image: All the bit fields of the MIPS R-Type, I-Type, and J-Type instructions]

The first thing that comes to mind is to make a table with perhaps 8 rows and 7 columns and do a great deal of fiddling around trying to get the spacing to look right. I expect that that would take me hours of frustration and I might still not be pleased with the results. Is there a convenient way to do it in LaTeX?

To be fully clear: I'd just like to know the general approach to make a diagram like this conveniently; I'm not asking for you to typeset that diagram for me. What I actually want to *do* is make a table similar to this but with a bunch of modifications. The details of that would make this question unnecessarily complex.

Comment: `matrix of nodes` in `tikz`? What code have you got? As it is, your question is likely to get closed as too broad and lacking an MWE.

Comment: @cfr I haven't written anything yet. I thought I'd ask here before spending hours trying to do it with `tabular`-type environments. An answer in terms of `matrix of nodes` would be fantastic. Is that specific enough?

Comment: Do-it-for-mes tend to be poorly received. Look at the `matrix` library in the Ti*k*Z manual and try it. If you get stuck, post your code and ask about the specific problem you're having. You can also search this site for examples.

Comment: A `tabular` is probably easier, though.

Comment: I think `bytefield` package is what you need: https://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield

Comment: @cfr Oops,  apparently it came across as a "do it for me". I just want to know a good *way* to do it—since I want to make something rather different than the diagram shown. I'll update the question to clarify that. Thanks already for your suggestions and @CarLaTeX's—these are already helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very easy job with [bytefield](https://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield} 
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}[leftcurly=., leftcurlyspace=0pt]{32}
\bitheader[endianness=big]{31,26,25,21,20,16,15,11,10,6,5,0} \\
\begin{leftwordgroup}{\makebox[\widthof{R-Type\ }][r]{R-Type\ }}
\bitbox{6}{opcode} & \bitbox{5}{rs} &
\bitbox{5}{rt} &\bitbox{5}{rd} &\bitbox{5}{sa} & \bitbox{6}{function}
\end{leftwordgroup}\\
\end{bytefield}\vspace{3ex}

\begin{bytefield}[leftcurly=., leftcurlyspace=0pt]{32}
\bitheader[endianness=big]{31,26,25,21,20,16,15,0} \\
\begin{leftwordgroup}{\makebox[\widthof{R-Type\ }][r]{I-Type\ }}
\bitbox{6}{opcode} & \bitbox{5}{rs} &
\bitbox{5}{rt} &\bitbox{16}{immediate}
\end{leftwordgroup}\\
\end{bytefield}\vspace{3ex}

\begin{bytefield}[leftcurly=., leftcurlyspace=0pt]{32}
\bitheader[endianness=big]{31,26,25,0} \\
\begin{leftwordgroup}{\makebox[\widthof{R-Type\ }][r]{J-Type\ }}
\bitbox{6}{opcode} & \bitbox{26}{istr\textunderscore index}
\end{leftwordgroup}\\
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that a bytefield package even existed. The LaTeX world never ceases to amaze!

Comment: @BenKovitz I'd never heard of it either.

Comment: @BenKovitz See my renewed answer, now it's all `bytefield` package, without the `\raisebox` trick.